# jQuery closest(), parents() and parent() affects multiple elements at same DOM level

Tags: jquery, parent, traversal, closest, parents

I am trying to traverse up the DOM to the closest DIV.  The markup below is below.

```
<div>
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div>
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div>
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

When I use any of the following:

```
$('.anchor').closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.anchor').parents('div').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.anchor').parent().parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

It affects all the DIVs like so:

```
<div style="background-color: red">
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

If I were to click the middle anchor I want this:

```
<div>
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red">
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
<div>
     <span>
           <a class="anchor">Text</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

I think I see why `closest()` would match all three DIVs as the closest DIV to the clicked anchor as it is generically matching DIV.

But when using `parents()` or `parent()` it's not as clear as the other DIVs are not a parent of a click anchor.  But I can also see where it might just be generically matching DIVs again at that level in the DOM.  Although it seems like `parents()` and `parent()` should maintain more of a contextual context when matching.

Comment: can you show your click event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you specify `$(".anchor")`, it is finding all the objects in your page that match the `.anchor` selector and then, one by one, doing `.closest('div').css('background-color', 'red')` on each of them.  If you want to scope it to only the parent div of the object that was clicked on, you need to use the click-on object as the starting point for your `.closest('div')` call like this:

```
$(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
```

This will then only affect the clicked on parent div starting from the `this` object.

You haven't shown the code for you click handler, but it could be like this:

```
$(".anchor").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

or, if you wanted to clear the other items that might have been red from previous clicks and then make this one red, you could do this:

```
$(".anchor").click(function() {
    var master$ = $(this).closest('div')
    master$.siblings().css('background-color', 'white');
    master$.css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: I think `.css('background-color', 'inherit')` would be more suitable.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me, overlooking the most simple and obvious issue.  I'm matching all anchors with the class anchor and moving up.  Since they all have the class anchor, they would all match.  Time to get some rest I think.  Thank you!

Comment: @JamesAylett - I was just using an example.  We have no idea what color it was before being set to red.  Perhaps it was white before.  This is just an example to show them how to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure, but setting it to inherit should cover more cases. It's a minor point, certainly :-)

Comment: @JamesAylett - actually, if you want it to go back to what the CSS might have specified for it, you would set `.css('background-color', '')`.  Lots of possibilities depending upon what the OP intends.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah yes, that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial node query `$('.anchor')` is matching all three `<a>` elements, so everything you do from then on (be it `closest`, `parents` or whatever) will happen once for each of those matching elements. If you use any of those approaches in a click handler, it won't cause you problems because it'll only be firing for the one element.

You'd probably be better off adding/removing classes, as that's a little easier than tidying up CSS you've added directly in using `.css()`.

Comment: True, for whatever reason that's what I used in the example.  The actual markup has a couple more things going on than just changing the background color.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.anchor').closest('div')` will find all the `.anchor` elements and find its closest div and apply the background color to all of them.

You should use `this` to refer to the element being clicked inside the click handler.

```
$(this).closest('div')..
```

Try this.

```
$(".anchor").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
$(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
$(this).parents('div').css('background-color', 'red');
$(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Hope this helps... :)